# Simplest solar panel home installation to power electric heaters?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, heat

**Background**: With the surging cost of electricity (I'm in Europe), I want to install solar panels to power electric heaters at home.

**Research = batteries are needed**: All setups I see include batteries (+charger controllers for the batteries.)

**My understanding regarding batteries**: The batteries serve two purposes: store energy as solar production doesn't necessarily align with the consumption AND regulate power output (constant output to prevent power cuts, minimum output so appliances can operate, maximum output so as to not damage appliances.)

**My problem with batteries**: They are expensive, and the moment I include them in my simulations they make the overall setup no longer cost effective.

---

**QUESTION: Can't we just skip batteries?** If all I want to power are basic electric heaters (essentially just resistors) AND I just want to power them during the day with whatever solar power is available, can't I just skip batteries altogether?

---

**My naive thought**: Basic electric heaters are just resistors, they don't contain any electronics, have no sensitive components, so my thought is that they should be able to produce heat with whatever solar power they receive, which would allow me to heat up my home as much and as cheaply as possible during the day (0 cost of batteries,) then at night I go to bed so I don't care if the installation doesn't generate any heat.

Comment: How big is your house?  Are you in Mallorca or the Netherlands?  My house has a 20kW gas fired heating system.  I also have a 9.8kW photovoltaic system and a 7.5kWh battery system.  The PV system is not up to providing enough power to heat the house.  The battery could only provide 20kW for less than twenty minutes.  You'll need to come up with some numbers to see if your plan would work.  How much energy does it take to heat your house? How much energy can you capture with a PV system?  How much space do you have for a battery?

Comment: Most solar installations with inverters does not have batteries, so your question is strange. Just buy a solar inverter?

Comment: Simplest solar heater is to attach some black panels and let them heat up. maybe add some reflectors or refractors if you need higher temp.  Why go electric when all you need is heat? Solar thermal

Comment: A more effective way to use solar energy is with a heat pump.  You get more heat energy pumping it out of the ground with electricity from a PV system than you get electrical energy from the sun.

Comment: @winny, why bother with an inverter? Run the heaters from DC.

Comment: @Transistor Are we not taking about regular AC heaters with thermostat?

Comment: You could also heat something such as a water tank.  As @JRE says: if you give some scaling numbers that will help a lot.

Comment: @winny, yes, the thermostat could be the problem with DC. I was thinking that one could run directly off the solar panels' variable voltage output into a resistive load but I hadn't considered MPPT and, given the the need for a DC thermostat relay this would be complicated by the variable voltage. It's about time I started to play with PVs!

Comment: @Transistor I saw someone test thermal panel into insulated water tank versus straight up PV into resistor in same water tank (impedance matched well for MPP but no MPPT). One would be led to think thermal panel has 100 % efficiency but the higher the water temperature the more losses due to radiation do for 90 deg C target temperature, the PV would win for a given area. Thermal was slightly cheaper. PV is more flexible. Food for thought.

Comment: Max, as others say, you must provide some numbers. There are so many ways to think about these problems. And if you need heat at night but get solar power during the day when you need it less, you could for example replace batteries with lots of *rock* or *concrete* with heating elements buried in them. The rocks will heat up, store the heat, and release it. Cheaper than a battery, anyway. But whether it can be applied or not to your situation is a whole other matter. We need lots and lots of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just skip batteries and the alternator and a lot of stuff if all I want to power are basic electric heaters AND you just want to power them during the day with whatever solar power is available.  You don't have to take my word for it if you can get a pv panel and some nichrome wire.  You will find that you reach a limit in power and temperature when you try to heat something large that constantly loses that heat.

Heck, you can skip electricity altogether and go solar thermal.  Stirling engine if you need to pump what you heat.  Much cheaper to scale too so you can keep scaling until you have enough, if you have the space.  Do some insolation calculations to get an idea of what you have available in your area, figure out what efficiency you need to get out of your available solar field, and maybe build a scaled down version to start and see if you can get to that efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Storage is needed. But not necessarily batteries.

You could re-purpose an old hot water storage tank, with solar panels driving an immersion heater element.

(Bypass its own thermostat, which isn't rated to switch DC. Or use the thermostat at low voltage, to switch a DC rated contactor. But you'll need some control system to prevent boiling for safety's sake).

Add a pump to circulate warm water through room radiators.

If your storage tank has a heat exchanger loop for a central heating system, you could add solar thermal heating too, and benefit from its much higher efficiency.